# Adding functionality to outlook 2013 send button in c#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am trying to store mail data(From,To,Cc,Bcc,Subject,etc.) in a local database on the click of Send button in outlook 2013.

Can it be done through the `ItemSend` event?

```
 Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
```

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should cast the `Item` parameter to `MailItem` using the `as` operator. If the result is not `null` it means that the item being sent is an email. You can access the required data from the `MailItem` object.

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
if(mailItem != null)
{
    // Access email data here
}
```